# Adding records to a table until the counter is true

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm developing a library management system with Java + MySql and I'm trying to add book records according to a counter. I just need to allow user to add books until the counter is >= 10. When it's 10 it should give a error message. If it's lower than 10 it program should allow the user to add a record. So far I manged to write this, but the result is not what I expect from the system. Any ideas on improving this.

```
    private void btn_addActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    try {             
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `read_with_us`.`book_inventory` WHERE book_title='" + txt_booktitle.getText() + "'");
        rs.next();
        int count = rs.getInt(1);

        if (count >=10) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry Maximum allowable quantity (10) has been reached!!");
        }
        else {
            String sql2 = "INSERT INTO `read_with_us`.`book_inventory` (`book_id`, `book_title`, `isbn_no`, `book_author`, `book_publisher`, `category_id`, `status`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";

            pst = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
            pst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(txt_bookid.getText()));
            pst.setString(2, txt_booktitle.getText());
            pst.setString(3, txt_isbnno.getText());
            pst.setString(4, txt_author.getText());
            pst.setString(5, txt_pubisher.getText());
            String category = (String) com_category.getSelectedItem();
            pst.setString(6, category);
            String status = (String) com_status.getSelectedItem();
            pst.setString(7, status);
            pst.execute();
            //Clearing the fields
            txt_booktitle.setText("");
            txt_isbnno.setText("");
            txt_author.setText("");
            txt_pubisher.setText("");
            com_category.setSelectedItem("1");
            com_status.setSelectedItem("Available");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Added");
            pst.close();
            rs.close();
            con.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error:" + " " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image: error]

[image: error-code]

```js
run:
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Books.btn_addActionPerformed(Books.java:656)
 at Books.access$200(Books.java:19)
 at Books$3.actionPerformed(Books.java:161)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
 at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
 at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: did you get any error or what you get?

Comment: It gives me the error message as null.

Error: null

Comment: can you show us the error please?

Comment: yes i know show us the error stuck, the error in your console

Comment: what `e.printStackTrace();` print in your console?

Comment: it gives NullPointerexception.  where is com_category defined ?is it a Class varaible in com_category.getSelectedItem();

Comment: I think one of the values u are passing in prepared statement might be null.And Also have you declared the statement also in class variables

Comment: please copy and past your error here dont show a screen shot!!

Comment: @YCF_L I have attached error code.

Comment: no, i really can't see the error, copy and past the error don't make an screen shot, it is not helpful

Comment: @YCF_L I've pasted the code, please have a look.

Comment: @DilumJayawardhana you dorgot the `rs = ps.executeQuery();` check answer

Comment: @YCF_L Yes manged to get that working after adding the code. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: you are welcome @DilumJayawardhana enjoy ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use `rs.next()` like that, instead use if :

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `read_with_us`.`book_inventory` WHERE book_title = ?");
ps.setString(1, txt_booktitle.getText());
rs = ps.executeQuery();
int count = 0;
if(rs.next()){
   count = rs.getInt(1);
}
```

Comment: This allow me to add the book, but how does the counter work here.

Comment: what did you mean @DilumJayawardhana is your error solved now?

Comment: No, User should only able to add 10 books, after the 10 books it should give the user an error message.

Comment: @DilumJayawardhana i mean the `NullPointException` is gone or not?